# Skip server in dictionary list instead of stopping code

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

So basically this code connects to servers and downloads files matching this pattern from a directory into another. However, if a server is not reachable, it stops the whole process. I want it to skip it to the next server instead. How can I do this?

Also it downloads every file containing `pc_dblatmonstat_` in it. While this is partially correct, I only need those files in which the names are like `pc_dblatmonstat_x_x` where x replaces the actual value of that file in the directory.

E.g. I want the file pc_dblatmonstat_tpc01n1_scl000101018.log instead of pc_dblatmonstat_tpc01n1.log

Here is what I have got

```
import os
import paramiko
import re

# 1. Create function
def get_server_files(local_path, host, port, username, password, remote_path, file_pattern):
    """Connects to host and searches for files matching file_pattern
    in remote_path. Downloads all matches to 'local_path'"""
    #Opening ssh and ftp
    ssh_con = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_con.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_con.connect(host, port, username, password)
    sftp_con = ssh_con.open_sftp()

    print('Connecting to', host)

    # Finding files
    all_files_in_path = sftp_con.listdir(path=remote_path)
    r = re.compile(file_pattern)
    files = list(filter(r.match, all_files_in_path))

    #Download files
    for file in files:
        file_remote = remote_path + file
        file_local = local_path + file

        print(file_remote + ' >>> ' + file_local)

        sftp_con.get(file_remote, file_local)
        #sftp_con.put(file_local, file_remote)

    sftp_con.close()
    ssh_con.close()

# 2. list of servers
# Add new dictionary for each server to this list
list_of_servers = [
    { 'host': '192.168.1.64',
      'port': 22, 
      'username': 'pi', 
      'password': 'pi', 
      'remote_path': '/home/pi/Desktop/logs/', 
      'file_pattern': 'pc_dblatmonstat_*_'},

      { 'host': '192.168.1.65',
      'port': 22, 
      'username': 'pi', 
      'password': 'pi', 
      'remote_path': '/home/pi/Desktop/logs/',  
      'file_pattern': 'pc_dblatmonstat_*_'}
]

# You could add the local_path to the function to define individual places for the
# files that you download.
local_path = r'C:\Users\urale\Desktop\logs\\'


# 3. Iterate through the list_of_servers, using the function above
for server in list_of_servers:
    get_server_files(local_path, **server)
```

Comment: What error is printed out when the server is unreachable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop, you can `try, except` the error when a server is unreachable and skip to the next one like this:

```
for server in list_of_servers:
    try:
        get_server_files(local_path, **server)
    except:
        continue
```

To solve your second problem, why not update the file_pattern to specify that there has to be a second 'x' as you described: `'pc_dblatmonstat_[^_]*_.*'`. This part `[^_]*` means that you expect any number of characters that are not an underscore, while the rest of the pattern specifies that there must be another underscore followed by any number of characters. As a result, files that have only one underscore, like `pc_dblatmonstat_tpc01n1.log` from your example, will not be counted

Comment: That was quick! Very much appreciated :). I did not know the exact values for my problems. Works like a charm now.

Comment: @Trunks no problem. Btw, I usually use this site called [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) to test out my regex patterns, as it also provides a nice cheatsheet for building regexs

Comment: @Trunks also the reason I commented on your original post about what error you encounter is because you may want to update the `except` to catch only the specific error you expect, in case something else goes wrong that you'd want to know about, rather than simply skipping over

Comment: That site is very useful. Will sure come in handy, thank you. The error simply tells that the server is not reachable and it stops. But that's okay, I only want it to skip it.